# How to use environment variable parameter in jq parsing

Tags: bash, jq

In the following bash code, I'm getting null as value instead of actual value. I'm using `jq 1.5` in Linux OS.

```
getProperty(){
    export PROP=$1
    export value_found=`cat my.json | jq '."env.PROP"'`
    echo "$1 = $value_found"
}

getProperty "first.name"
getProperty "last.name"
```

Contents of `my.json`

```
{"first.name":"Adam", "last.name":"Eve"}
```

My program requires to get value for properties selected randomly, so the property name is not known before runtime (hence the reason for trying to use parameters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is right, but you *don't* need to export the variables/use the environment variables here. Just pass in the arguments and use the internal `jq` logic to import variables from shell.

The key here is to access arguments containing `.`, wrap them over `[]`

```
getProperty(){
    jq --arg namearg "$1" '.[$namearg]' < json
}
```

and now call with the args as needed

```
getProperty "first.name"
"Adam"
getProperty "last.name"
"Eve"
```